# iOS kiosk app needs to print without dialog box

Tags: ios, printing, airprint, kiosk-mode

Is there a way to bypass the dialog box and use default print configuration when printing with "air print" on an iPad?

I am trying to use it in kiosk mode and automatically print without giving end user ability to change any settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way of doing that!